# how many number of live datanodes required when settings dfs.namenode.replication.min=2

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My HDFS cluster has 3 datanode. When I set dfs.namenode.replication.min=2, my cluster can not exit safe mode at startup and keep throwing this error: **The minimum number of live datanodes is not required. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.**
I am wondering how many datanodes is required when setting that property to 2, and is there any formula between **number of live datanode** and **dfs.namenode.replication.min**?

Comment: There's no "formula". The answer is at least 2... But number of datanodes isn't the same as having live, healthy nodes... The error is saying your cluster isn't healthy, so go look at the logs of the datanodes or namenode UI to see all healthy nodes